# Bash logic for finding previous calendar day

Tags: bash, date

I want to find out the past calendar day using bash .

I have tried the following

> Today's date    : `20130701`  Expected Output : `20130630`

**Code1 :**

```
myTime=`TZ=$TZ+24 date +'%Y%m%d'`
echo $myTime
```

Output

```
20130629
```

**Code2 :**

```
timeB=$(date +%Y%m)
sysD=$(date +%d)
sysD=$((sysD-1))
echo $timeB$sysD
```

Output

```
2013070
```

**Code3 :**

```
yest=$(date --date="yesterday")
echo "$yest"
```

Output

```
date: illegal option -- date=yesterday
usage:  date [-u] mmddHHMM[[cc]yy][.SS]
        date [-u] [+format]
        date -a [-]sss[.fff]
```

**Code4 :**

```
$ date +%Y%m%d -d "yesterday"
```

Output

> 20130701

None of them gave the correct output . Can anyone please advise me the correct way to get the desired results.

OS Version : SunOS 5.10

Comment: What does `date --version` return?

Comment: The `--date` parameter is probably a GNU extension. And incidentally `--version` and `--help` too. It's not there on other unices or e.g. OS X.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @Dancrumb added the OS version onto the question.

Comment: @inafzger Mate tried the accepted answer in that question , but that doesn't work for me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system in question is most likely Solaris. This will work on Solaris:

```
TZ=GMT+24+<YOUR_LOCAL_TIME_ADJUSTMENT> date +'%Y%m%d'
```

**Edit:**
To account for DST (example for GMT+11 / GMT+10 with DST):

```
actualdate=$(date +'%Y%m%d%H%M')
nondstdate=$(TZ=GMT+11 date +'%Y%m%d%H%M')

if [ $actualdate = $nondstdate ] ; then
    TZ=GMT+35 date +'%Y%m%d'
else
    TZ=GMT+34 date +'%Y%m%d'
fi
```

**Edit 2:**
Bullet proofing for random TZ and DST:

```
gmthour=$(date -u +%k)
localhour=$(date +%k)
tz=$(( gmthour - localhour ))
echo Your Timezone is $tz
yesterdaytz=$(( 24 + tz ))
echo the offset for yesterday is $yesterdaytz

TZ=GMT+$yesterdaytz date +'%Y%m%d'
```

Comment: It will fail some times unless you are in UTC. TZ has to be GMT+24-LOCAL_ADJUSTMENT, ie, for the East Coast of the US with DST, GMT+20.

Comment: @zany My local time adjustment varies as per the DST , so sometimes it is +10 and sometimes +11 . How do I handle that ?

Comment: The option `-u` will switch to GMT-universal time bypassing the normal conversion to local time. Then you'd need to compare to get your current TZ. I'll try to extend the answer.

Comment: Ok, the `-u` option won't help. But you can work out your current TZ by comparing the actual output to a fixed TZ. I added tested code to the answer.

Comment: mate still not sure if this si printing out the correct answer `actualdate=$(date +'%Y%m%d%H%M')
nondstdate=$(TZ=GMT+11 date +'%Y%m%d%H%M')
echo $actualdate
echo $nondstdate
if [ $actualdate = $nondstdate ] ; then
    TZ=GMT+35 date +'%Y%m%d'
else
    TZ=GMT+34 date +'%Y%m%d'
fi
echo $TZ`   Output: `201307011039
201306301339
20130629`

Comment: added bash arithmetic expressions to detect the current TZ and some debugging echos.

Comment: @zany mate this one works perfectly well for change in month .

Comment: @zany sorry mate , didn't consider the scenario . It still gives an error . Code

    `#!/bin/bash
    gmthour=$(date -u +%H)
    localhour=$(date +%H)
    echo $gmthour
    echo $localhour
    tz=$(( gmthour - localhour ))
    echo $tz`

Error

    `22
    08
    MyFile.ksh: line 6: 08: value too great for base (error token is "08")`

Comment: Can you confirm that setting a TZ greater than GMT+23 is the source of the error? I guess Bash and Date won't be much use then.

Comment: `tz=$(( 10#$gmthour - 10#$localhour )) echo $tz yesterdaytz=$(( 24 + tz )) echo the offset for yesterday is $yesterdaytz myTime=`TZ=GMT+$yesterdaytz date +'%Y%m%d'` output `22 08 14 the offset for yesterday is 38 myTime 20130630` expected is `20130701`, it is currently `20130702` here.

Comment: @zany this logic basically doesn't work when GMT hour is between 15-24 (DSP diff 10 hours) and 14-24(GMT diff 11 hours)

Comment: Oh sorry, I get it now. That should've been %k (hour, space padding) not %H (hour zero padding) in the test. Btw. is %z (timezone) available?

Answer (score 4):

You probably have python.

```
python -c "import datetime; print datetime.date.today () - datetime.timedelta (days=1)"
```

Though, if date would support the `-d` flag, then that would be my preferred solution.

Comment: verified that your answer works. But mate was looking for a solution is bash so accepted a bash solution :)

Answer (score 3):

Based on the usage message, I don't think you're on OS X.  If you are on OS X, you can use the `-v` flag, but only relative to the current date/time:

```
$ date +%Y%m%d
20130630
$ date -v-1d +%Y%m%d
20130629
```

If you have `ksh` available, you can use it.  I'm not sure of the full syntax available so I don't know if you can specify the base date, but you can do it relative to today:

```
$ ksh -c 'printf "%(%Y%m%d)T\n" yesterday'
20130629
```

Solaris (as of version 10) still ships with the ridiculously old `ksh88` as its default `ksh`.  You should be able to find `ksh93` (which supports the above syntax) in `/usr/dt/bin/ksh`:

```
$ /usr/dt/bin/ksh -c 'printf "%(%Y%m%d)T\n" yesterday'
20130629
```

If you have `tclsh` available, you can use it:

```
$ echo 'puts [clock format [clock scan "yesterday"] -format %Y%m%d]' | tclsh
20130629
$ echo 'puts [clock format [clock scan "20130701 - 1 day"] -format %Y%m%d]' | tclsh
20130630
```

You've already said `--date` doesn't work, but for completeness: On systems using the GNU version of `date`, you can use `--date` or `-d`:

```
$ date +%Y%m%d
20130630
$ date +%Y%m%d -d yesterday
20130629
$ date +%Y%m%d -d '-1 days'
20130629
$ date +%Y%m%d -d '20130701 - 1 day'
20130630
```

Comment: Input: `ksh -c 'printf "%(%Y%m%d)T\n" yesterday'`  , Output: `(%m0)T` Input: `echo 'puts [clock format [clock scan "yesterday"] -format %Y%m%d]' | tclsh` , Output: `ksh: tclsh:  not found`

Comment: Try `/usr/dt/bin/dtksh -c 'printf "%(%Y%m%d)T\n" yesterday` .

Comment: I did the same. It comes up with a screen , waiting for me to enter some stuff. Input `$ dtksh -c 'printf "%(%Y%m%d)T\n" yesterday` , Output: `$    `

Answer (score 0):

GNU date

```
$ date "+%Y%m%d" -d 'now -1 day'
20130629
```

Comment: His system isn't Linux. GNU date is not available here. (And it's most likely not OS X or FreeBSD.)